# Android Google Maps layer - drawable icon

Tags: android, google-maps, drawable

I'm looking for the resource identifier for the Android "Layers" icon that you see in the Google Maps app. It's used to select layers, and has 3 offset rectangles sitting on top of each other.

[image]

I've looked in the android.jar and can't find it. I've also looked at this site, but can't seem to find it. Is there a more complete gallery of built-in graphics?

http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm looking for the resource identifier for the Android "Layers" icon that you see in the Google Maps app.

Google Maps is not part of the Android SDK, nor part of the Android Open Source Project. Hence, that icon is not available, in all likelihood.

> Is there a more complete gallery of built-in graphics?

All of the drawables in the SDK are in your SDK installation on your development machine.

Comment: i was referring to a a website that has all the graphics laid out like the one I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

whoever needs the layer icon can use below

[image: map drawable icon]

Answer (score 0):

This icon contains in Android Studio. In case someone need it:

```
R.drawable.ic_baseline_layers_24
```

[image]